# Can you use SuperTweet to read and search Twitter API 1.1?

Tags: twitter, arduino, twitter-search

I'm using an Arduino to access the Twitter Search API 1.1. However, I'm finding it very difficult to do the new [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) process. Further, doing the new OAuth process on the Arduino is very costly in terms of memory.

Looking for alternative options, I stumbled upon [SuperTweet](http://www.supertweet.net/). The website however only discusses posting tweets as the main example for the use of their service. Is it possible to use their service to access the new Search API of Twitter and other parts of API 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot search, but you can get your home timeline and search that yourself.